# Python Multiprocessing : AssertionError: can only join a started process error when multiple process are spawned in loop

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I have spawned multiple process using for loop and appended each process into an array after starting it.

```
for param in multiples_100:
    p = Process(target=calculate, args=(param,))
    processes.append(p)
    p.start()
p = Process(target=calculate, args=(200,))
processes.append(p)
for p in processes:
    p.join()
```

when I try to join all processes It's throwing `AssertionError: can only join a started process`

Comment: You didn't start `p = Process(target=calculate, args=(200,))`.

Comment: Your start is next to append ... try to start before p = Process(target=calculate, args=(200,))

Comment: This could be an error for Python 3.8+ on MacOS. Fix: https://github.com/python/cpython/issues/77906#issuecomment-1093788469

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not start the final process outside the loop.

```
for param in multiples_100:
    p = Process(target=calculate, args=(param,))
    processes.append(p)
    p.start()
p = Process(target=calculate, args=(200,))
p.start()
processes.append(p)
for p in processes:
    p.join()
```

should fix it.